# Coordinate Geometry Parabola and Line Intersection

Tags: geometry

Can someone please explain why $\alpha + \beta = -\frac{b}{a} = \frac{4}{3}$ for the image below?

Where $a$ and $b$ are constants that come from: $y^2-3y=5(\frac{1-y}{3})$

[image]

Comment: You can arrange your equation as $3y^2-4y-5=0$ so the sum of roots is $\frac 43$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the quadratic polynomial $ay^2+by+c$, then 
$$ay^2+by+c=a(y-\alpha)(y-\beta)$$
So
\begin{align}
ay^2+by+c&=ay^2-a(\alpha+\beta)y+a\alpha\beta
\end{align}
By equaling the coefficients of $y$ we get
\begin{align}
-a(\alpha+\beta)&=b\\
\alpha+\beta&=-\frac{b}{a}
\end{align}